# MQL4/5 how to make connection (login) to broker with PHP

Tags: php, mql

I am creating website in php that will store user account number, password and broker name (ip), that account will be connected automaticaly to MQL4/5 software in same moment user saves data in database.

Problem i have now is that user can save invalid data that will cause invalid connection to MQL4/5, and i want to check it to be sure all is valid before connection.

Is there any way to connect to broker with php or js, and check if credentials are correct (account number and password) before i store it into database ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Sanja, could you define what you mean by 'invalid data', and tell us why that causes an 'invalid connection'? A bit of code will always help to clarify things.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware At the moment i don't have any code because i don't know how to send data to broker to check for connection and there is no any documentation that can help with that. By 'invalid data' i mean user can save wrong account number, password that will fail when i try to connect to broker with MQL software.

Comment: It seems, but I'm not sure, you think that the user's account number and password are used to make a connection to MySQL. This is not so. Your PHP code used its own credentials to connect to the database, so a connection cannot fail due to what an user enters.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i guess you didn't understand me, i save account number and password into database that is later pulled from database to connect to MQL4/5 software, this is not MySql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but it's not easy.

You can only authenticate with a broker's Metatrader server using a Metatrader client terminal.

That being said, you could launch a Metatrader web-terminal in a headless selenium instance, login using the supplied credentials, and check the authentication result from the resulting html.

[image]